# Making file extention as a css class by using glob function

Tags: php, javascript, glob

My PHP knowledge is kind of limited, and I was trying to search for different PHP/JavaScript solutions, but nothing helped me to make it work, so I'd just try to ask the question directly.

I have the following PHP code that loads all the images from a specific folder on server:

```
foreach(glob($images_path . '*.*') as $filename){
echo '<img src="' . $filename . '" class="preview" />';
}
```

Now, in order to give different styles to the images, based on their kind, I want to recognize the extension of the file, whether with JavaScript/jQuery or PHP, and to put it as a class (preferably, but could be some other idea)... let's say, after the class "preview" which I already have in the code. It could be similar to the extension, just without the dot, of course; e.g. *class="preview png"*.

Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: use `class="preview '.pathinfo($filename, PATHINFO_EXTENSION).'"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
foreach(glob($images_path . '*.*') as $filename){
   $ext = pathinfo($filename, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
   echo '<img src="' . $filename . '" class="preview ' . $ext . '" />';
}
```

Comment: Sorry, @xdazz, my reputation is too low to vote it up, but that works 100%! Thank you very very much!

Answer (score 0):

try with this.

```
foreach(glob($images_path . '*.*') as $filename){ 
  $extension = str_replace('.', '', strrchr($filename, '.'));
  echo '<img src="' . $filename . '" class="preview '. $extension .'" />';
}
```

Comment: Thank you, @johesh_pi, for your solution. The one of xdazz worked for me, so I will go with it, but will keep this topic for future reference, and this might be helpful for somebody else. Thanks again.